# Bookshelf.js - Passing models to collection.atttach()

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

The [bookshelf documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-attach) indicates that I should be able to pass an array of models into `collection.attach()`, and they demonstrate this with the following code:

```
var admin1 = new Admin({username: 'user1', password: 'test'});
var admin2 = new Admin({username: 'user2', password: 'test'});

Promise.all([admin1.save(), admin2.save()])
  .then(function() {
    return Promise.all([
    new Site({id: 1}).admins().attach([admin1, admin2]),
    new Site({id: 2}).admins().attach(admin2)
  ]);
})
```

It doesn't seem to work in my case, however. My save operation works fine if I pass in an array of ids:

```
export function create({ blocks, tags, ...rest }) {
  const attributes = {
    blocks: JSON.stringify(blocks),
    ...rest
  }

  return Post.forge(attributes).save().then(post => {
    return post.tags().attach(tags.map(t => t.id)).then(() => post.refresh())
  })
}
```

However, if I try to pass in the `tags` instead, like this:

```
return post.tags().attach(tags).then(() => post.refresh())
```

Then I receive an error:

```
Unhandled rejection error: column "id" of relation "posts_tags" does not exist
```

Am I misreading the documentation? Should I not be able to do this?